# passing custom data from <a> to jQuery to show confirmation message before delete

Tags: jquery

How can I pass custom data to the jQuery event handler, specifically from the `$(this)` element? In HTML5, I probably can legally write:

`<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id=5" data-id="5">delete</a>`

although I still feel a bit awkard about that. How about prior to that?

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
   return confirm("Do you really want to delete " + $(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Any best practices?

Comment: Actually, that's a pretty clean way to do it (although it's not "valid" before HTML5, all browsers will just ignore the attribute).

Comment: so what do people do prior to html 5? they just ignore the spec?

Comment: @Jake pretty much. That or find some other way to store the data they need (like a hidden field, for example).

Comment: Or parse the `href` attribute, but it's probably not worth the hassle (and wouldn't be very robust).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use attr()

jQuery.data() reads html5 `data-` attributes using data() method which is also a method for storing data objects in an element

```
var id=$(this).data('id');
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

As far as only being html 5, lots of bogus attributes have been used for years, browsers typically just ignore them

Comment: so, does this work with any data-xxx attributes or only if the document is HTML 5?

Comment: does not have to be html 5 doctype, so answer is yes